# issue with foreign key in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am facing a referance issue

empid is not insert in the table when employee generate the experiance then not display the experiance data on the index page?

HomeController.cs

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly dbozeeEntities dbemp;

        public HomeController()
        {
            dbemp = new dbozeeEntities();
        }

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var list = dbemp.employees.ToList();
            return View(list);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(employee emp)
        {
            var create = dbemp.employees.Add(emp);
            dbemp.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Experiance", new { empId = emp.empid });   //here going to experiance page
        }

        public ActionResult Experiance(employee emps)
        {
            //ViewData["empid"] = emps.empid;

            return View(new experiance() { empid = emps.empid });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Experiance(experiance exp,employee emps)
        {
            //ViewData["empid"] = emps.empid;

            var create = dbemp.experiances.Add(exp);
            dbemp.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<DemoOzeeTechno.Models.employee>
@using DemoOzeeTechno.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    IEnumerable<experiance> exp = ViewData["empid"] as IEnumerable<experiance>;
}
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.empname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.emailaddress)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.contactno)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.empname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emailaddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contactno)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.empid }) |
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.empid }) |*@
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.empid })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>CompanyName</th>
        <th>YearOfExperiance</th>
    </tr>

    @if (ViewData["empid"] != null)
    {
        foreach (experiance ex in exp)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@ex.companyname</td>
                <td>@ex.yearofexp</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Experiance.cshtml

```
@model DemoOzeeTechno.Models.experiance

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Experiance";
}

<h2>Experiance</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>experiance</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.companyname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.yearofexp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.yearofexp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.yearofexp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
               @* @Html.LabelFor(model => model.empid, "empid", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.empid)

                @*@Html.DropDownList("empid", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.empid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Database Design:

[image]

experiance data inserted in table **but issue is Does not Displaying the experiance data in index page**

[image]

**Watch Window:**

[image]

empis is not insert in the table and experiance data not display on the page that is the issue??

Comment: why give the -1 point? any reason for give the -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should know that `ViewData` get loss data while redirection from one action to another, So you have two options to pass `empid` from one `Action` to another one is to use `Session` and other is pass data in query string. So I would prefer a query string. So here is how you can do this.

First, you need to pass created `empid` to Experience action by the query string.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(employee emp)
    {
        var create = dbemp.employees.Add(emp);
        dbemp.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Experiance",new{empId=emp.id});   //here going to experiance page
    }
```

Now pass data to your view so that it post this id with newly created experience.

```
    public ActionResult Experiance(int empId)
    {
        return View(new experiance(){empid=empId});
    }
```

In the view you need a hidden field which will store this id into create experience form and submit along with experience fields.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.empid)
```

Now in you Experience post-action you don't need to set empid explicitly it will get it from posted form values.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Experiance(experiance exp)
    {  
        var create = dbemp.experiances.Add(exp);
        dbemp.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Updated**

To show the experience table on index page get all the experience list from the database and store it to ViewData.

```
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = dbemp.employees.ToList();
        ViewData["empid"]=dbemp.experience.ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
```

Comment: give an error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'DemoOzeeTechno.Models.employee', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DemoOzeeTechno.Models.experiance'.

Comment: I think this line give an error because when redirection occur then display the above error?

Comment: @see my url : ```http://localhost:3450/Home/Experiance?empId=1004 ```

Comment: Oh sorry, I've updated my answer now please use this public ActionResult Experiance(int empId)
    {
        return View(new experiance(){empid=empId});
    }

Comment: Just replace the employee with experience inside Experience get action when returning new instance

Comment: empis insert in the table thanks for the support but I still I am facing issue see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ib23.png  experiance data not displayed on the index page?help

Comment: I update my code in question experiance data is not displayed on the index page?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer, you need to get all the experience list on Index action and store into ViewData

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215738/discussion-between-raju-and-habib).